# Spring Data JPA Many to Many with extra column

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

I'm trying to do an many to many relation between two table. The relation contains extra information (a date). I'm trying to achieve that using Spring Data JPA and I'm testing using unit test. The test fail giving the error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find ....JoinEntity with id ....JoinEntity@5934ca1e; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find ....JoinEntity with id ....JoinEntity@5934ca1e
```

Here is my code:

Entity A:

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name= "tableA")
public class EntityA
{
   /** The primary key. */
   @Id
   private Integer id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
   private Set<JoinEntity> bs;

   //... getters and setters
}
```

Entity B:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name= "tableB")
public class EntityB
{
   /** The primary key. */
   @Id
   private Integer id;

   private String name;

   //... getters and setters
}
```

Join entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="joinTableAB")
@IdClass(ABId.class)
public class JoinEntity implements Serializable
{

   @Column(name = "join_date")
   private Date date;

   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
   private EntityA a;

   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
   private EntityB b;

   //... getters and setters
}
```

Repository for A:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<EntityA,Integer>
{
}
```

Repository for B:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface BRepository extends CrudRepository<EntityB,Integer>
{
}
```

The simple test class:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

/**
 * Testing for AtmosphericConditionsRepository.
 */
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ARepositoryTest.class})
public class ARepositoryTest
{
   @Autowired
   ARepository aRepository;

   @Autowired
   BRepository bRepository;

   @Test
   public void test()
   {
      EntityA a0 = new EntityA();
      a0.setId(0);
      a0.setName("a0");
      EntityA a1 = new EntityA();
      a1.setId(1);
      a1.setName("a1");

      a0 = aRepository.save(a0);
      a1 = aRepository.save(a1);

      EntityB b0 = new EntityB();
      b0.setId(0);
      b0.setName("b0");
      EntityB b1 = new EntityB();
      b1.setId(1);
      b1.setName("b1");

      b0 = bRepository.save(b0);
      b1 = bRepository.save(b1);

      Set<JoinEntity> joinEntities = new HashSet<>();
      JoinEntity je = new JoinEntity();
      je.setDate(new Date());
      je.setA(a0);
      je.setB(b0);
      joinEntities.add(je);
      a0.setBs(joinEntities);

      aRepository.save(a0);
   }

}
```

The class specified in @IdClass:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

public class ABId implements Serializable
{
   private EntityA a;

   private EntityB b;

   public ABId()
   {
   }

   public ABId(EntityA pA, EntityB pB)
   {
      a = pA;
      b = pB;
   }

   public EntityA getA()
   {
      return a;
   }

   public EntityB getB()
   {
      return b;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object pO)
   {
      if (this == pO)
      {
         return true;
      }
      if (pO == null || getClass() != pO.getClass())
      {
         return false;
      }

      ABId abId = (ABId) pO;

      if (a != null ? !a.equals(abId.a) : abId.a != null)
      {
         return false;
      }
      return b != null ? b.equals(abId.b) : abId.b == null;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode()
   {
      int result = a != null ? a.hashCode() : 0;
      result = 31 * result + (b != null ? b.hashCode() : 0);
      return result;
   }
}
```

Extended stacktrace:

```
2017-10-18 08:30:48.696  INFO 6460 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@de3a06f testClass = ARepositoryTest, testInstance = ....ARepositoryTest@58a90037, testMethod = test@ARepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@76b10754 testClass = ARepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{interface ....ARepository, interface ....BRepository, class ....JoinEntity, class ....ABId, interface ....ARepository, interface ....BRepository, class ....JoinEntity, class ....ABId}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@4493d195, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@4e1d422d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@5c8ff52f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@3cb1ffe6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer@274bc460, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@2c039ac6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b57696f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@5e13f156]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as id1_6_0_, entitya0_.name as name2_6_0_ from tablea entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=?
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as id1_6_0_, entitya0_.name as name2_6_0_ from tablea entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=?
Hibernate: select entityb0_.id as id1_7_0_, entityb0_.name as name2_7_0_ from tableb entityb0_ where entityb0_.id=?
Hibernate: select entityb0_.id as id1_7_0_, entityb0_.name as name2_7_0_ from tableb entityb0_ where entityb0_.id=?
Hibernate: select joinentity0_.a_id as a_id2_2_0_, joinentity0_.b_id as b_id3_2_0_, joinentity0_.join_date as join_dat1_2_0_, entitya1_.id as id1_6_1_, entitya1_.name as name2_6_1_, entityb2_.id as id1_7_2_, entityb2_.name as name2_7_2_ from join_tableab joinentity0_ inner join tablea entitya1_ on joinentity0_.a_id=entitya1_.id inner join tableb entityb2_ on joinentity0_.b_id=entityb2_.id where joinentity0_.a_id=? and joinentity0_.b_id=?
2017-10-18 08:30:49.035  INFO 6460 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@de3a06f testClass = ARepositoryTest, testInstance = ....ARepositoryTest@58a90037, testMethod = test@ARepositoryTest, testException = org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find ....JoinEntity with id ....ABId@5a9ba131; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find ....JoinEntity with id ....ABId@5a9ba131, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@76b10754 testClass = ARepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{interface ....ARepository, interface ....BRepository, class ....JoinEntity, class ....ABId, interface ....ARepository, interface ....BRepository, class ....JoinEntity, class ....ABId}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@4493d195, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@4e1d422d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@5c8ff52f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@3cb1ffe6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer@274bc460, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@2c039ac6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6b57696f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]].

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find ....JoinEntity with id ....ABId@d3513f0a; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find ....JoinEntity with id ....ABId@d3513f0a

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:389)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.save(Unknown Source)
    at ....ARepositoryTest.test(ARepositoryTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find ....JoinEntity with id ....ABId@d3513f0a
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:509)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: where is the `@IdClass` for the "JoinEntity"? since you have more than 1 `@Id` you need one

Comment: Are you sure it's mandatory? I'm creating a composite key using @Id twice.

Comment: I tried with @IdClass, the result is the same, the message is only slightly different (when indicating which id it does not found). Any other idea?

Comment: Can You show more stack trace, plz? (and just a guess: write a Dao for JoinEntity (not expensive) and use that in your test.)

Comment: Of course it's required. If you have a composite key then you would have nothing to input into `em.find(...)` if you have no defined type!

Comment: I added the IdClass and a more stacktrace (error remains the same). @xerx593 I add a more complete code with DAO (the DAO was then calling the repository and produced the same error) but I reduced it to the minimum to provide compact, reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed the Cascade type on the collection :/.

After adding it:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="a",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<JoinEntity> bs;
```

It works fine now.